# Why are applicationFrame and statusBarFrame obtained from two different objects?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I think `statusBarFrame` and `applicationFrame` complement each other exactly to form the whole screen's bounds.  And the frame's value is relative to the "raw" portrait orientation screen coordinates (which I think is the screen's bounds).  So for example, when an iPad is rotated upside down, the output of

```
NSLog(@"the status bar frame is %@", 
    NSStringFromCGRect([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]));

NSLog(@"the applicationFrame is %@", 
    NSStringFromCGRect([[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]));
```

is

```
the status bar frame is {{0, 1004}, {768, 20}}
the applicationFrame is {{0, 0}, {768, 1004}}
```

But a questions is, how come these two values that complement each other come from two different objects: the application instance and the `UIScreen` instance, but not from the same object?  (say, both from the `UIScreen` object?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, it's because there is only one status bar per application, but there could be multiple screens (e.g. via AirPlay) for a single application.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Application Kit API and also Objective-C paradigms are based around the concept of ownership.

An application owns its statusBar while the Screen owns the Application Window.

For example (No cars here) I own the table in my House but the landlord owns my House.

And more to the point Apple created the Appkit API and has created its own 'physics' and consistency . If you want your own universe and physics  make your own API.

Have a look at a WWDC 2012 lecture about creating long lasting code. It goes into this really well.

Comment: would it make sense if these two frames belong to the same object? (with ownership considered).  These two frames seem like siblings, with a common parent, if using your analog, is somewhat like a table and a chair that complement each other